# How can I reload something called by 'require'?

Tags: perl

My main perl project has a series of require statements that calls other perl scripts. Example snippet from the main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require "./test1.pl";
require "./test2.pl";
require "./test3.pl";
require "./test4.pl";
```

If I made a change to test3.pl, how can I reload it into memory and have it's changes reflect into the currently running instance of my project? At the moment I have to restart the entire project if I made a small change to test3.pl.  I would like to put this into a subroutine if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two ways to load code from a module - `use` does so as compile time.
`require` does so at runtime.

When it does this, it includes the module in `%INC`.

You can see this happening if you:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%INC;
```

So to *reload* - delete it from `%INC` and re-run the `require`.

```
delete ( $INC{'./test3.pl'} );
require './test3.pl';
```

You may also find useful:

```
no warnings 'redefine';
```

Which you can use to temporarily shut off "subroutine redefined" warnings. (You are using `strict` and `warnings` right?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Module::Reload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Reload) or [again](https://metacpan.org/pod/again). But, maybe it's time to re-think your design.